# Flutter: Show Text depending on whats chosen (FilterButtonWidget)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, widget

I have some FilterButtonWidgets for a car searching app. So the user can sort by brand, model, price, etc.
Everything works fine but I would like to see which brand, which model, which price, etc. was chosen. How can I display what the user have chosen? This is what the relevant part of the code looks like:

```
Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        FilterButtonWidget(
                          title: 'Brand',
                          item: constants.brand,
                          type: 'brand',
                        ),
                        FilterButtonWidget(
                          title: 'Price',
                          item: constants.price,
                          type: 'price',
                        ),
```

When the user picks for example a brand, a BottomSheet pops up and he can chose for example BMW. But when the BottomSheet disappears, the user can't see anymore what he has chosen.
All the brands and prices, and everything else is saved in my file contants.dart and it looks like this:

```
Map<String, bool> brand = {
  'Audi': false,
  'BMW': false,
};

List<double> price = [
  0,
  20000,
  25000,
  30000,
];
```

... and so on.
I've added a screenshot of a section of my screen so you can better understand.
[image]
Can you please help me out? Thank you very much!

Comment: just create two variables and updated their values as per your logic and pass them to your Text widget

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, I'm sorry

Comment: FilterButtonWidgets are Custom or you are using any dependency?